# Complex - returning information that is not found in the database

Tags: mysql

I have a strange query to perform from a website.  I have sets of arrays that contain pertinent ids from a many tables - 1 table per array.  For example (the array name is the name of the table):

```
Array Set 1:
array "q": 1,2,3
array "u": 1,5
array "k": 7

Array Set 2:
array "t":   2,12
array "o":  8, 25

Array Set 3 (not really a set):
array "e": 5
```

I have another table, Alignment, which is not represented by the arrays.  It performs a one to many relationship, allowing records from tables q,u, and k (array set 1, and recorded as relType/relID in the table) to be linked to records from t and o (array set 2, recorded as keyType/keyID) and e (array set 3, recorded as keyType/keyID).  Example below:

```
Table: Alignment
 id   keyType  keyID   relType  relID 
 1       e       5        q       1
 2       o       8        q       1
 3       o       8        u       1
 4       t       2        q       2
 5       t       2        k       7
 6       t      12        q       1
```

So, in record 6, a record with an id of 12 from table t is being linked to a record with an id of 1 from table q.

I have to find missing links.  **The ideal state is that each of the ids from array set 1 have a record in the alignment table linking them to at least 1 record from array set 2**.  In the example, alignment record 1 does not count towards this goal, because it aligns a set 1 id to a set 3 id (instead of set 2).

Scanning the table, you can quickly see that there are some missing ids from array set 1: "q"-3 and "u"-5.

I've been doing this with script, by looping through each set 1 array and looking for a corresponding record, which generates a whole bunch of sql calls and really kills any page that calls this function.

Is there some way I could accomplish this in a single sql statement?

**What would I like the results to look like (ideally):**

recordset (consisting magically of data that didn't exist in the table):

```
relType   |    relID
    q            3
    u            5
```

However, I would be elated with even a binary type answer from the database - were all the proper ids found: true or false?  (Though the missing records array is required for other functions, but at least I'd be able to choose between the fast and slow options).

Oh, MySQL 5.1.

User Damp gave me an excellent answer using a temporary table, a join, and an IS NULL statement.  But it was before I added in the wrinkle that there was a third array set that needed to be excluded from the results, which also ruins the IS NULL part.  I edited his sql statement to look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM k2
LEFT JOIN alignment
USING ( relType, relID )
HAVING alignment.keyType IS NULL
OR alignment.keyType = "e"
```

I've also tried it with a Group By relID (i always thought that was a requirement of the HAVING clause).  The problem is that my result set includes "q"-1, which is linked to all three types of records ("o","t", and "e").  I need this result excluded, but I'm not sure how.

---

Here's the sql I ended up with:

```
SELECT *
FROM k2
LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT *
    FROM alignment
    WHERE keyType != 'e' and 
    ( 
    (relType = 'q' AND relID IN ( 1, 2, 3 ))
    OR 
    (relType = 'u' AND relID IN ( 1, 5 ))
    OR 
    (relType = 'k' AND relID IN ( 7 ))
    )

    )A
    USING ( relType, relID )
    HAVING keyType Is Null
```

I have to dump the values for the IN qualifiers with script.  The key was not to join to the alignment table directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to go this route:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS k2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE k2 (relType varchar(10),relId int);
INSERT INTO k2 VALUES 
  ('q',1),
  ('q',2),
  ('q',3),
  ('u',1),
  ('u',5),
  ('k',7);
SELECT * FROM k2
LEFT JOIN Alignment USING(relType,relId)
HAVING Alignment.keyType IS NULL
```

This should work well for small tables. Not sure about very large ones though...

**EDIT**

If you wanted to add a WHERE statement the query would be as follow

```
SELECT * FROM k2
LEFT JOIN Alignment USING(relType,relId)
WHERE Alignment.keyType != 'e'
HAVING Alignment.keyType IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is an awesome answer and it works on my example.  There is a wrinkle I should have mentioned.  Its possible for the relType/ID to appear in the table, but not linked to an "o" or "t" record.  So I just added some other criteria to the having clause.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Okay, gosh, this query takes 14 secs to execute.  I wonder why it is so slow :(

Comment: @Todd how big is your table? Do you have indexes on relType and relId? You can replace the * in the SELECT to something more optimized depending on the indexes you have...

Comment: I didn't have them indexed - once I did, it runs much quicker.  Thanks again.

Comment: Double shucks.  It turns out the "wrinkle" isn't as easily accommodated as I thought.  After more thorough testing, I find I am getting bad results.

Comment: @Todd what about adding a `WHERE Alignment.keyType != "e"` in the query?

Comment: I can use having and where in the same statement?  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes you can http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html HAVING is very different from WHERE (even though it may appear similar)

Comment: I've tried a bunch of syntaxes, and I'm not getting it right... probably just the order of the statements.  Could you show me how that would look?  Do I need and AND between the where and having?  From your link it seems the where comes first.

Comment: Actually, I think we're on the wrong track here.  I'm getting an empty result set now.

Comment: @Todd `WHERE Alignment.keyType != 'e' || Alignment.keyType is null`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how persnickety this is.  This doesn't work. It leaves out the "q" 3 answer that it should find.  In order to find it, we need the join row that would read q-3-e-5, which we eliminated with the where != "e".  I don't know why that didn't get joined to a null column instead.

Comment: @Todd I don't have enough info to help you further... But I guess you have the right tools to figure it out now. Experiment with the select without the HAVING clause just to see what happens with just the JOIN and the WHERE clauses and re-add the HAVING once you've figured out your solution

Comment: Okay, I got something that works now using all the pieces you gave me, just not the way you used them.  Thanks for your guidance.  I put the final sql in my OP.